# Can't figure out "invalid syntax" message

Tags: python, syntax

I've got this piece of code that is a part of a student database I'm making for class and I really can't determine why I'm getting invalid syntax on a particular line (line 3, userints).

```
def userints():
   choices = int(input("Choose Student ID 1-6:")
   userints = int(choices)
   print (userints)
   if userints == 1:
       for line_number, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('init2.txt', inplace=1)):
           if line_number == 1:
               continue
           else:
               sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: Missing `)` on the previous line.

Comment: Also, wrong indentation on line 5.

Comment: Note that when you get a syntax error on a line, it's often caused by a problem on the line above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `)` on the previous line. It should be:

```
choices = int(input("Choose Student ID 1-6:"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about second brace.